# How to query and sum across tables?

Tags: mysql

What is the query that will result in the result below (see image)?

Formula for Ending Balance: Deposit + Beginning Balance - transaction
Beginning Balance on the next day should be the Ending Balance of the previous day

[image]

```
create database sample_dbbal;
create table beginning_balances
( 
    postdate date, person varchar(30), currency varchar(10), beginning_balance int
) ;
```

`` insert into beginning_balance ( postdate, person, currency,beginning_balance)
values ('1/25/2015', 'johnpaul','usd','500')
;

create table transaction_details
(postdate date, person varchar(30), currency varchar(10), transactionamount int 
) ;

insert into transaction_details (postdate, person, currency, transactionamount)
values ('1/25/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '55');
insert into transaction_details (postdate, person, currency, transactionamount)
values ('1/28/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '68');
insert into transaction_details (postdate, person, currency, transactionamount)
values ('1/30/2015', 'johnpaul','usd', '20');
insert into transaction_details (postdate, person, currency, transactionamount)
values ('2/20/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '10');


create table deposit_details
(postdate date, person varchar(30), currency varchar(10), deposit int
) ;

insert into deposit_details (postdate, person,currency,deposit)
values ('1/25/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '50');
insert into deposit_details (postdate, person,currency,deposit)
values ('1/28/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '300');
insert into deposit_details (postdate, person,currency,deposit)
values ('1/28/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '25');
insert into deposit_details (postdate, person,currency,deposit)
values ('1/25/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '100');
insert into deposit_details (postdate, person,currency,deposit)
values ('1/25/2015', 'johnpaul', 'usd', '20');

select 
    `postdate`, 
    `person`,
    `currency`,
    sum(`totaldeposit`),
    sum( `totalamount`),
    sum( `beginning_balance`),
    (sum(`totaldeposit`) + sum( `beginning_balance`)) -  sum( `totalamount`) as `endingbalance`
from
(
select `postdate`, 
       `person`,
       `currency`,
       sum(deposit) as `totaldeposit`,
       0 as `totalamount`,
       0 as `beginning_balance`
from deposit_details
group by postdate,person,currency
union all
select `postdate`,
       `person`,
       `currency`,
       0 as `totaldeposit`,
       sum(transactionamount) as `totalamount`,
       0 as `beginning_balance`
from transaction_details
group by postdate,person,currency
union all
select `postdate`,
    `person`,
    `currency`,
    0 as `totaldeposit`,
    0 as `totalamount`,
   `beginning_balance`
from beginning_balances
    group by postdate,person,currency   
) temp123
group by `postdate`,`person`,`currency` ``

--  I got stuck on how to continue the computation for Ending Balance.

Comment: Please use representation of code in text format rather than images. Also post your attempts always. Learn more about posting from: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SameerMirji here, can you help me with this one o got stock on how to continue the computation for my ending balance for other dates. thank you !

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: what programming language are you using.
Either you use a stored procedure / use your programming language as it will be a loop to get the previous ending balance.

was trying something: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d66794/25)

Comment: @chaeralee: Would make a lot of sense to use a stored procedure to fetch the expected results.